# Paginator Symfony advice for making query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, pagination

I am trying to make a paginator in Symfony and this is how my code looks like:

Controller class:

```
class MovieDisplayController extends Controller
{

    public function showAction()
    {
        //Records:
        //$movies = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Movie')->FindAll();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT m
            FROM AppBundle:Movie m'
            )->setMaxResults(5)->setFirstResult(0);
        $movies = $query->getResult();
        //$resultAmount = $query->getResult()-count();

        //Pagination: 
        $filterVariables = "";
        $currentPage = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
        $totalPages = /*Example: */20; //something like: $this->count($movies) / $recordsPerPage

        return $this->render('movies/index.html.twig', array(
            'movies' => $movies,
            'filtervariables' => $filterVariables,
            'page' => $currentPage,
            'totalPages' => $totalPages
            ));
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly fine, however I want to make my paginator work and I have to pass some `GET` variables in the `LIMIT` part of a query (at least that is what I found out after doing some searching).

First of all, let me ask if any of you would know, the use of the `GET` variables in the "pagination" part of the class, would that be the proper way in Symfony to call those? I have seen something like: `$foo = $request->query->get('page');` but that does not seem to return anything (or at least not the same as the `$_GET['page']` variable), or am I trying to do something that is not possible (anymore)?
(Also I do not wish to make use of routing for this)

Secondly I would like to know if it is possible (or how) to count the amount of results I would get by using `$movies = $query->getResult()`.

If anyone has any tips or advice for me to optimize my code and make it working, I would gladly want to know.

**Edit:** My pagination works fine now, if there should be any tweaks to make it even work more perfectly, feel free to add a comment or an answer if it's an important change. ([Code used](http://pastebin.com/ZHjs5hMk))

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See KnpPaginator (https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle), it will perhaps help you

Comment: I have seen this one before, but since I already have this much code (nearly complete) I prefer to just use the custom code I already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### GET and SET variables within symfony

There are several possibilities how to pass variables to controller. The simplest will be to use the routing.

```
/**
* @Route("something/{page}/{limit}", defaults={"page" = 1, "limit" = 10}, name="show_action")
*/
public function showAction($page, $limit)
{
}
```

Then you will be able to use `$page` and `$limit` directly inside your controller.

If you don't want to use routing you may also use session instead:

```
public function showAction(Request $request)
    {
$this->get('session')->get("page");
$this->get('session')->get("limit");
    }
```

### Counting records

You may count your sql records using DQL:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder()
              ->from('Movie', 'f')
              ->getQuery();


$total = $query->select('COUNT(f)')
               ->getQuery()
               ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: For the get method I do not wish to routing, that was actually why I left it out. Pardon me for not adding this to my question. For the second part f my question, whenever I run the `select()` part I will be returned with the following error message: `Attempted to call an undefined method named "select" of class "Doctrine\ORM\Query"`. Did I forget something?

Comment: Would `$resultAmount = count($repository->createQueryBuilder('m')->getQuery()->getResult());` not do the job aswell? It does return the correct number.